# How to give tool tips (title) in locale language (UTF-8) in IE and Chrome?

Tags: html, tooltip, title

I want to show tool tips (title) in locale specific language by UTF-8 formatted values.

I tried It's working in firefox but not working in IE and Chrome. What I have to do for this problem?

`<div title='(some UTF-8 formatted value)'`

above code is working perfectly in firefox.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Please define "doesn't work". What "doesn't work"? What does it do, what should it do?

Comment: Page displays locale (hindi) body text just fine but the title tag of the pages display plain squares. This seems to work perfectly in firefox (for locale specified UTF8 formatted). But I want it to work in IE and Chrome. Is there a solution?

Comment: Squares means the font used to display the tooltips does not contain the necessary characters. I don't know if there's a way to influence what font the browser uses to display tooltips.

Answer (score 1):

The font(s) used in tooltips depend(s) on the browser, which may or may not use settings made at the operating system level. Thus it may be controllable by the user, though few users know about this. In any case, it is outside the control of the author.

This implies that the repertoire of characters you can use there may vary. A plain square or rectangle in text typically indicates that there is a recognized character but it cannot be displayed because it is not present in the font(s) being used.

Partly for reasons like this, authors are more and more moving towards using other techniques than the `title` attribute, namely “CSS tooltips” (or maybe “JavaScript tooltips”). This lets you use the same fonts as in the textual content or, if preferred, to set some suitable other fonts.